# pontrjagin ring of the homology of iterated loop suspension

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, geometric-topology, hopf-algebras, loop-spaces

In [The homology of C n+1 spaces, n>=0, F. Cohen](http://www.math.uchicago.edu/%7Emay/BOOKS/homo_iter.pdf), proof of Theorem 3.1 and proof of Theorem 3.2 (p. 228 - 243)

[image]
[image]

I totally do not understand the proofs of these two theorems from page 228 to page 243 in Section 3 and Section 4 of  [The homology of C n+1 spaces, n>=0.](http://www.math.uchicago.edu/%7Emay/BOOKS/homo_iter.pdf)
Could you explain the ideas for the proof, especially for the proof of Theorem 3.2?